# Reliable Android Open Softphone

Tags: android, open-source, voip

I am looking for a reliable open source softphone for Android. The built-in one got removed from AOSP. I am using GrapheneOS which is AOSP-based and I do not want to install Play Services. I don't care about push notifications. I have a public IP on the phone via VPN.

Currently using Linphone, but it recently got so buggy it's unbearable. Baresip(+) has never even worked.

Comment: You can find some open SIP clients [in my list here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_cheapcall#group_858). Several of them are available from F-Droid, so no need to install Play Services. Maybe Simlar, SipDroid or LumiCall work for you? If you find a match, be welcome to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) ;)

Comment: Sipdroid and LumiCall aren't maintained. Tried everything in FDroid. I cant parse your site. Do you have an explanation of the symbols besides the program names?

Comment: Yes of course. Just click the blue "?" (help) button in the upper right corner of the page, which brings you to the (corresponding, context-sensitive) [help page](https://android.izzysoft.de/help.php?topic=applists) ;)